# ejecución de evento dentro de una nueva ventana

Tags: javascript

Tengo una duda con la que llevo peleandome un buen rato y me gustaría que me ayudarais, la función es la siguiente:

```
function abrirVentana() {
        var nuevaVentana = window.open();
        var cursos = ["XX", "XX", "XX", "XX", "XX", "XX"];
        for (let i = 0; i < cursos.length; i++) {
            var div = document.createElement("div");
            nuevaVentana.document.body.appendChild(div);
            var input = document.createElement("input");
            div.appendChild(input);
            input.type = "button";
            input.value = cursos[i];
            input.addEventListener("click", function () {
                nuevaVentana.alert("Ha presionado en "+this.value);
            });
        }
    }
```

Lo que estoy intentando es que al hacer click en cualquiera de los botones que están dentro de la nueva ventana me salte un alert dentro de la misma mostrando el value del boton correspondiente pero por alguna razón no salta, ¿que podría ser? 
 He probado a poner el event.**preventDefault()**; justo antes de terminar la función y entonces si me funciona por alguna razón, y no entiendo exactamente el porque ya que no lo veo necesario aquí, igual me equivoco, pido ayuda.
Gracias de antemano!

Answer (score 0):

Vale, creo que ya se donde estaba el problema.

Esta función se supone que deberia de ejecutarse al hacer click en un enlace (creado previamente), y al parecer si le asignamos el evento a un enlace si que hay que hacer uso del **preventDefault()**; para evitar la redirección del mismo y que haga lo que nosotros le indiquemos. 
Este ha sido el código resultante y que me funciona:

```
window.onload = function () {
        document.getElementsByTagName("a")[0].addEventListener("click", abrirVentana);
    }


    function abrirVentana(evento) {
        var nuevaVentana = window.open();
        var cursos = ["XX", "XX", "XX", "XX", "XX", "XX"];
        for (let i = 0; i < cursos.length; i++) {
            var div = document.createElement("div");
            nuevaVentana.document.body.appendChild(div);
            var input = document.createElement("input");
            div.appendChild(input);
            input.type = "button";
            input.value = cursos[i];
            input.addEventListener("click", function () {
                nuevaVentana.alert("Ha presionado en "+this.value);
            });
        }
        evento.preventDefault();
    }
```

Esto no haría falta añadir si a lo que le asignamos el evento es a un button por ejemplo ya que no tiene un evento por default como el enlace, corrijanme si me equivoco en algo ya que todavía no estoy muy seguro de si esto es así.

Un saludo.